# Trying to trigger an event when an image is visible on the screen using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to trigger an event when an image appears on the users screen.  The images that are appearing on the screen are from a slideshow and when each image appears I am looking to have text fade on top of the visible image.

I have used the if($('#element').is(':visible') syntax which has worked fine for the first slide but it does not work on the proceeding slides.  I have looked for answers everywhere online for this but unfortunately there is no specific answer.

```
            <script>

            var slideIndex = 1; 

            var t;

            showSlides(slideIndex);

               function plusSlides(n) {

                 slideIndex = slideIndex + n;
                 clearTimeout(t);
                 showSlides(slideIndex);
                 console.log(slideIndex);

            }

               function currentSlide(n) {

               showSlides(slideIndex = n);

            }

               function showSlides(n) {

               var i;

               var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

                    if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}

                    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}

                    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}

                    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

                          slides[i].style.display = "none";

              }

              slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

             t=setTimeout(showSlides, 7500)

           };


            if($('#slide1').is(':visible')) {

              $("#fadeTxt1S1").delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);

              $("#fadeTxt2S1").delay(3000).fadeIn(3000);

            };

            if($('#slide2').is(':visible')) {

              $("#fadeTxt1S2").delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);

              $("#fadeTxt2S2").delay(3000).fadeIn(3000);

            };

            </script>

            <html>

            <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide1">

                       <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src="HomePage/slide3b.jpg">

                       <p id="fadeTxt1S1">"convallis malesuada."</p>

                       <p id="fadeTxt2S1">"tempus convallis "</p>

             </div>


            <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide2">

                       <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src="HomePage/test2.jpg">

                       <p id="fadeTxt1S2">"amet nisl tempus"</p>

                       <p id="fadeTxt2S2">"tac lectus see"</p>

             </div>

            </html>
```

Comment: What event makes each slide appear/disappear? What to do, probably, is to put code into a listener for that event, which does your `is(':visible')` check. The problem with the question as it stands is that it doesn't replicate your problem - the code doesn't actually run, and it's almost certain that there is other code that is relevant (judging by the `fade` class).

Comment: I have now added the JavaScript code to show how the slideshow is being implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example. The only real change is to put the check for visibility into the code at the point when the slide transition has just happened. The reason is that your check just occurs once on page load, and it really needs to run after the transition. Other changes are just tidying of the code. I also added some css so that the fade effects show up.

By the way, there are probably better ways to code the fade effects. For instance, rather than checking which slide is visible, you could simply do something like this

```
$(slides[slideIndex-1]).find('p').eq(0).delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);
$(slides[slideIndex-1]).find('p').eq(1).delay(3000).fadeIn(3000);
```

The point is that you already have a reference to the container of the elements you want to appear, so you can refer to them directly.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;

var t;

showSlides(slideIndex);

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    if($('#slide1').is(':visible')) {
        $("#fadeTxt1S1").delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);
        $("#fadeTxt2S1").delay(3000).fadeIn(3000);
    };

    if($('#slide2').is(':visible')) {
        $("#fadeTxt1S2").delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);
        $("#fadeTxt2S2").delay(3000).fadeIn(3000);
    };
    t=setTimeout(showSlides, 7500)
};
```

```css
            .fade, .fade p {
                display:none;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide1">
            <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src="HomePage/slide3b.jpg">
            <p id="fadeTxt1S1">"convallis malesuada."</p>
            <p id="fadeTxt2S1">"tempus convallis "</p>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade" id="slide2">
            <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src="HomePage/test2.jpg">
            <p id="fadeTxt1S2">"amet nisl tempus"</p>
            <p id="fadeTxt2S2">"tac lectus see"</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for the edit with regards to using .find instead of (' :Visible').  Could I ask you for an explanation as to the workings of the code? I'm new to coding so trying to get my head around it :)

Comment: `$(slides[slideIndex-1])` gives you a reference to a jquery object that you can think of as representing the current slide.
`find('p')` returns a collection of all the <p> tags that are contained within the jquery object.
`eq(0)` says "I only care about the element at position 0" - ie the first one.
All that, put together, returns you the same thing as you would get from saying either `$("#fadeTxt1S1")` or `$("#fadeTxt1S2")`, but it does it from the context of the container.